# COMO DESCOBRIR O INDEX DE UMA MATRIZ NO PYTHON

Tags: python, matriz, índices

Como faço para descobrir um index da linha da matriz no python, o código foi feito usando list coprehensions.

Minhas Funções:

```
def cria_matriz(coluna, linha):
    matriz = [[c for c in range(coluna)] for k in range(linha)]
    return matriz

def isfloat(num):
    try:
        float(num)
        return True
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return False

def cria_float(linha, coluna):
    num = input(f"Digite o numero da linha {linha} e coluna {coluna}")

    while not isfloat(num):
        num = input(f"Digite o numero da linha {linha} e coluna {coluna}")

    return num

def print_matriz(matriz):
    [print(c) for c in matriz]

def modify_matriz(matriz):
    mt = [[cria_float(coluna=coluna, linha=linha) for coluna in linha] for linha in matriz]

    return mt
```

o problema se da na função cria_float (tem como parametros, linha e coluna), criei ela para permitir que o usuário modifica e insira numero na matriz, dentro da descrição uso f strings para orientar o usuário o index da linha\coluna da matriz.

dentro do modify_matriz há um list comprehesion usado para percorrer cada casa da matriz, onde executo a função cria_float.

o problema e que a coluna esta retornando a posição certa, porem a linha esta retornando a lista inteira, como faço para conseguir indexar corretamente a linha.

Answer (score 0):

Reproduzi seu código e entendi seu problema na função modify_matriz. Você está fazendo:

```
mt = [[cria_float(coluna=coluna, linha=linha) for coluna in linha] for linha in matriz]
```

Explicando por partes. No primeiro list comprehension (mais externo) você faz:

```
[ "alguma coisa" for linha in matriz]
```

Neste passo você está retornando a **linha toda** para que "alguma coisa" execute algo. Logo após no list comprehension interno você está fazendo:

```
[cria_float(coluna=coluna, linha=linha) for coluna in linha]
```

Você está iterando sobre a **linha toda (variável linha)**, até aí tudo bem, mas você esta passando esta mesma **linha toda (variável linha)** para a função *cria_float* que imprime o valor da linha toda.

Além disso, os índices das colunas só estão aparecendo corretamente porque sua função de criação da matriz cria com os valores sequenciais à partir do zero (coincidindo com os índices).

Como eu recomendo que seja declarada a função *modify_matriz*:

```
def modify_matriz(matriz):
    mt = [[cria_float(coluna=coluna, linha=linha) for coluna in range(len(matriz[linha]))] for linha in range(len(matriz))]

return mt
```

Comment: @AugustoVasques Pergunta editada para trazer o código.